# ICMP request | By Virtual NIC | no response

Tags: virtualization, ping, nic, wireshark, icmp

### **The Issue:**

I want to Understand what's going on when I'm sniffing from the host machine with `Wireshark` for instance packets that are coming from the VM that is bridged directly to the physical network. When i'm sniffing from the host machine ip `.14` i can see traffic that comes from the VM which is ip `.26`.

- Question 1 - I'm sending from the VM a `ping request` to ip `8.8.8.8` with the command `ping -c 1 8.8.8.8`. While i'm sniffing in my host machine with wireshark i observed that i have 2 requests and 1 reply such as the attached image: [press to get in the attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SII6a.png) and as you can see this particular request is described as `"no response found"` by Wireshark. But after that we can see another request that send although we've used `ping -c 1` to send one time! whats going on here?
- Question 2 - How it's possible that i'm in the host machine ip `.14` and i can see the VM network traffic that is bridged? I can guess it's because of the broadcast request? When the VM ip `.26` is trying to reach (by request) to ip `8.8.8.8` it asks who is `8.8.8.8`? and it passes other the `.14` maybe gets this broadcast and saves the packet? and this is the reason that we can see the traffic between `.14` to `8.8.8.8`? or am i wrong here?

### **Technical Information about The described system:**

- I have a host machine IP 192.168.1.14
- "Under" This host machine i have a VM with `Bridged: Connected directly to the phisical network`. Which means that it's acts like an individual NIC, Just like another NIC connected seperately to the common router with the host. So `.14` and `26` acts like different NIC that are connected to the Common gateway router (i think).
- The host is windows, And the "guest" VM is Linux.